# In App Purchase open source implementations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, in-app-purchase

I'm looking in open source implementations on top of the In App Purchase, maybe with the server-side implementation.

I know about http://urbanairship.com, but I prefer do it in-house.

Comment: Good for you.  Do you have an actual question?

Comment: The end "?" in the title? ;) Seriously, the question is if exist a open source implementation or library to ease IAP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on [MKStoreKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/introducing-mkstorekit-%E2%80%93-version-3/) - small StoreKit wrapper. It gives some abstraction about what goes inside SK. However, you'll need to change it a bit to fit your needs

Hope this will help you